# Eclipse reports bug on valid cpp inheritance

Tags: c++, eclipse, multiple-inheritance

Eclipse is reporting a bug on "new Listener()", though this compiles and executes with g++.  Note the classes have more data than listed here as this is trimmed down, so removing the seemingly empty classes is not an option.  Is there something that I can add/change to make both Eclipse and g++ happy.  I will not be able to change the Base* classes though.

```
class BaseIntf {
public:
    virtual ~BaseIntf() {}
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class BaseImpl: public virtual BaseIntf {
public:
    virtual void foo() {}
};

class ListenerBaseInft: public virtual BaseIntf {
};

class Listener: public ListenerBaseInft, public BaseImpl {
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Eclipse:
    // The type 'Listener' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'BaseIntf::foo'
    Listener* listener = new Listener();
    listener->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE. Which compiler you use?

Comment: Does `ListenerBaseInft` really share an abstract interface with `BaseIntf` and need to be treated as one?

Comment: Mark B, yes, this is the interface that was put in place well before I got the to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ has a feature called *dominance*. Normally, when a class (say `A`) is derived from two classes (say `A1` and `A2`), each implementing the same virtual function (say `void f()`), the derived class needs to implement that function as well. A pure virtual function counts as an implementation too.

However, there is an exception: when `A1` is itself derived from `A2`, then `A1`s implementation of `f()` is said to *dominate* that of `A2`, and the latter is excluded from consideration. Thus, `A` does not have to reimplement `f()`.

Your compiler probably fails to take that exception into account. It's a compiler bug.

To work around it, define `foo` in `Listener`:

```
void foo() { BaseImpl::foo(); }
```

which is ugly, but so is the compiler bug.

Comment: Thanks n.m.  That's a little ugly, and since the Eclipse usage is low around here, I might have a hard time submitting a change solely to support Eclipse at the risk of affecting the rest of the code.  But this is good to know.

Comment: And the bug has been open since 2011-07-09
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=351612